# How to get a value from a for loop in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I written the following code to randomly select items n items from a list and place the selections in a new list
The code is below

```
let random_extract list n =
    let l =  ((List.length list)- 1) 
    and acc = []  in
    for i = 1 to n do 
        (List.nth list (Random.int l) ) :: acc  (* Line 447 *)
    done;
    acc
;;
```

When I load the file that contains this code I get the following error

```
File "all_code.ml", line 447, characters 2-40:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
val random_extract : 'a list -> int -> 'b list = <fun>
```

Two questions , 
Question 1: what does this warning mean.

Secondly when I run this function I dont get the list expected but an empty List.

Question 2: how do I get the value of acc from inside the for loop

Comment: Iterating on a list with a `for` loop and `List.nth` is poor taste and inefficient. Why don't you code a real tail recursion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What Jeffrey Scofield said, and also:

```
let random_extract list n =
let l =  ((List.length list)- 1) 
and acc = ref []  in
for i = 1 to n do 
    acc := (List.nth list (Random.int l) ) :: !acc  (* Line 447 *)
done;
!acc
```

If you are going to use a `for` loop for something like that, then `acc` must be a reference, i.e., a *mutable* value. In Ocaml and ML in general `let x = ...` defines an *immutable* value. Next, when you wrote `(List.nth list (Random.int l)) :: acc`, that just meant "look, I can make a list". Nowhere did you say that the newly constructed list has to be assigned to anything, in particular it was not assigned to `acc` (which it couldn't, because `acc` is immutable). Ocaml issued a warning because it saw that the body of your `for` loop produces a list, but Ocaml knows that the body of a `for` loop ought to produce a unit ("void" in C/C++/Java mis-terminology).

Using a `for` loop like that is ugly. The Right Way is to do it like this:

```
let random_extract lst =
  let l = List.length lst - 1 in
  let rec extract = function
   | 0 -> []
   | n -> List.nth lst (Random.int l) :: extract (n - 1)
  in
    extract
```

If you are new to Ocaml you really should invest time to understand the above code completely. After that, you should study the following code, and make sure you understand why it is more efficient that the first version (look up "tail recursion"):

```
let random_extract lst =
  let l = List.length lst - 1 in
  let rec extract acc = function
    | 0 -> acc
    | n -> extract (List.nth lst (Random.int l) :: acc) (n - 1)
  in
    extract []
```

Comment: Your solution could result in the same element being randomly selected  multiple times. I created a new solution which deletes an element once it is chosen.

Comment: So could yours. I was just copying what you did. Nowhere did you say repetitions were disallowed. Anyhow, put your code on http://dpaste.com/ and we can comment on it, if you wish.

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like you're starting to work with OCaml and have an imperative programming background.  Probably the best advice for thinking about OCaml (and functional programming in general) is to start to think of all your program constructs as expressions, i.e., things with values.  In imperative programming, many things (like a for loop, a while loop, an if statement) don't have values, they just "do" things.  In functional programming, everything has a value.

Since OCaml isn't a *pure* functional language, one value is reserved to represent an expression that just "does" something.  The value is written like this: `()`.  The type of this value is known as `unit` (it is the only value of the type `unit`).

Since a `for` loop is intended to just "do" things, even in OCaml, the expression inside the loop should have type `unit`.  But you've written something that has a list type.  Anything that looks like `x :: y` must be a list, because the `::` constructor creates a list.  That's what the compiler is warning you about.  The inside of your loop should have type `unit`, but it has a list type.

Your second problem is that the expression `x :: y` does *not* change the value of `y`.  This is the essence of functional programming.  All the expression does is compute a new value (a list).  It doesn't change any of the values that appear in the expression.  Because of this, `acc` ends up with the same value it started with.

I would really suggest that you solve this problem using recursion (as suggested by Basile Starynkevitch), rather than trying to use imperative constructs like the `for` loop.  It will result in much more idiomatic OCaml code.  If you really need to use a `for` loop for some reason, you need to make your `acc` variable be a mutable value, and you need to mutate (change) it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I answered this question.

```
let rec remove_at_k list i acc =
    match list with 
        [] -> []
      | h::t -> if (i = 1) then acc @ t else remove_at_k t (i-1) (acc@[h])
;;

let random_extract lst n =
    let rec extract lst2 acc = function 
        | 0 -> acc
        | n -> let l = List.length lst2 in let index = (Random.int(l)) in 
               (*  print_list lst2; Printf.printf " with I %d\n" index ; *)
          extract (remove_at_k lst2 (index+1) []) (List.nth lst2 index :: acc) (n-1)
    in 
    extract lst [] n
;;
```

I couldnt use the solution provided above by Andrej Bauer since that solution does not guarantee that the same element won't be selected twice. The solution above does that.

Comment: By the way, your algorith, is quadratic, and I do not see how to improve the time complexity. If you use arrays instead of lists, we can make it linear time.